# Is "$\subset$" a symbol of first-order language of set theory?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic, first-order-logic

Is "$\subset$" a symbol of first-order language of set theory ?

in Mathematical introduction to logic by Enderton , he says that the only 2-place predicate is $\in$ , but i can't understand why $\subset$ doesn't exist ? how can we deal with set theory without subset notion ?

Comment: Instead of saying that $A\subset X$ you can say $A\in P(X)$. Is this the reason?

Comment: @Sigur , this makes sense !

Comment: @Sigur: Not really, since the power set symbol isn’t in the language either.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott , you mean because there is no such function give us the power set of given set ?

Comment: No, I mean that just as $\subseteq$ is not a symbol of the language, so also the $\wp$ of $\wp(x)$ is not a symbol of the language.

Comment: @MathsLover Because $P(X)$ can be defined as the set of all subsets of $X$, where subset is defined as in B.Scott's answer below. The symbol is just shorthand.

Comment: There have been occasional attempts to make a set theory that is based on the subset relation, not the membership relation. In that case, $\subset$ would be a symbol of the language, and $\in$ would not be! None of the attempts has drawn serious attention from the mathematical community.

Comment: And to add to @B.D’s comment, it’s shorthand for something whose existence is guaranteed by the power set axiom.

Comment: About a theory with $\subset$ as primitive instead of $\in$ (i.e.the inclusion relation is primitive instead of the membership relation) see [Mereology](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/mereology/). As said by @André Nicolas, it has no support from mathematicians, in spite of the "revamping" made recently by a distinguished philosopher : D.K. Lewis, *Parts of Classes* (1991).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You don’t need to have a two-place predicate $\subseteq$ in the language, because you can define it by a formula: $x\subseteq y$ is an abbreviation for

$$\forall z(z\in x\to z\in y)\;.$$

One ends up defining a great many things that aren’t actually in the formal language: $0$, $\omega$, $\wp(x)$, $\bigcup x$, etc., but keeping the formal language to a minimum simplifies some technical arguments quite a bit — anything that involves induction on formulas, for instance.

Comment: Oh! Yes, I remember now. Thanks. +1